# Choosing right Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-commons

I would like to use `ToStringBuilder` from `Apache Commons Lang` in my IntelliJ IDEA java project. I place ID `org.apache.commons` in `Download Library from Maven` menu  and found many links:

[image]

I suppose this means that many maven repositories has this library. How to know which one is correct one? What is the logic of finding right library source?

Comment: Just compare the groupId and the artifactId. Should match `org.apache.commons:commons-lang3`

Comment: That is because the libary has many versions, You would want to pick the latest.

By default the the lookup hits repo at Maven2 which is https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ But this does not have option to search and check versions directly. You can most likely check you library in https://mvnrepository.com/ and then pick up the version of library you want to include.

Comment: Try 'mvn dependency:tree' to check details about commons-lang

Comment: Maven Central search:  https://search.maven.org (which searches in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to your sentence

> I suppose this means that many maven repositories has this library

I know the following popular maven repos.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
https://search.maven.org/search?q=commons-lang3

As far as common-lang3 library is concerned, all the repos have the correct library.
While searching in intellij, it also displays other libaries which use commons-lang3.
You have to select group id, artifact id and version to set the dependency.